# Getting error after finishing some steps in Installshield

Tags: winforms, visual-studio-2013

I am new to INSTALLSHIELD. I have developed an application in Winforms. Now I am having a requirement  of making setup file of that application so that it can be installed in many PC's. I have tried it, but after few steps I am getting the following error. I don't know what wrong in it.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You should try the workaround suggested [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/c9936d80-087d-4cad-93bf-ca4873889773/the-debugger-cannot-continue-running-the-process?forum=vsdebug), or look at this specific [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12363928/the-debugger-cannot-continue-running-the-process-unable-to-start-debugger). This is a quite frequent error and if you actually searched you would have been able to find an answer by yourself.

Comment: I have made my solution explorer as my Start up Project. But still I am getting same error :-).